# Delete selected data in a checkbox

Tags: php, checkbox

I'm making a website on which I have a set of data with checkbox. I need to delete multiple rows from database when I select multiple checkboxes. I don't know how to pass the id of the selected checkboxes to next page. Please help me.

Here is my code:

```
$select_qry="select * from data";

$result=mysql_query($select_qry);
$rows=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($rows>0)
{
   ?>
   <form action="delete_submit.php" method="post">
   <?php
   for($i=0;$i<$rows;$i++)
   {
      $arr=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
      $id=$arr['id'];
      $name=$arr['name'];
      //echo $id;echo "<br>";echo $name; 
      ?>
      <input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $id;?>">
       <?php
   }

}

?>
```

How can I pass the selected checkboxes' id to the next page? Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Try to format your code first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when form will be submitted then `$_POST['checkbox']` will be set and contain the array of selected ids.

In your delete script

```
if(isset($_POST['checkbox']) && count($_POST['checkbox']) > 0){
   $deleteIds = $_POST['checkbox'];   // it will be an array
   $sql = "DEFRE FROM tablename WHERE id in (".implode("," , $deleteIds).") ";

   // run the query
}
```